# "AttributeError" while accessing instance variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables, attributeerror

Python is raising the below exception when running my script. Could somebody please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vinsunny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\test.py", line 28, in <module>
    test.my_func()
  File "C:\Users\vinsunny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\test.py", line 23, in my_func
    print('non secret no. from test_func: ', self.number2)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'number2'"
```

```py
class Test():

    __class_secret_number = 100

    def __secret_func(self):
        self.number1 = 1
        self.__secret_number1 = 11
        print('You cannot see this unless accessing from the Class itself')

    def test_func(self):
        self.number2 = 2
        self.__secret_number2 = 22

    def my_func(self):
        self.__secret_func()
        print('Secret no. from class: ', self.__class_secret_number)

        print('non secret no. from secret func: ', self.number1)
        print('Secret no. from secret func: ', self.__secret_number1)

        # These two prints raise an exception.
        print('non secret no. from test_func: ', self.number2)
        print('Secret no. from test_func: ', self.__secret_number2)

test = Test()
test.my_func()
```

Comment: Facing this issue. Digged in google, no solution found.

Comment: You don't call `test_func`. So `number2` is never assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time the offending print statement is executed, the `number2` attribute on your `Test` instance has not been defined.

The first time the `number2` attribute gets set is in the `test_func()` method. i.e. Attempting to access `number2` before calling `test_func()` will result in the error you are observing.

You should assign a default value to `self.number2` in the initializer for the `Test` class. You could also call `test_func()` before calling `my_func()`. But, either way, it's still good practice to initialize all instance attributes in `Test.__init__`.

The interpreter will raise an exception for the same reason when you try to access the undefined attribute `__secret_number_2` in `my_func()`.

Comment: Thanks dude. It's working. Didn't think in that way.

Comment: Just created stackoverflow account so i couldn't upvote since i have <15 reputation.

Comment: Accepted. Yea sure i will come back once i have 15 reputation.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help!

Comment: came back with 15+ reputation.. Upvoted your answer.. Thanks once again..

Answer (score 0):

`test_func` is never called, so `number2` and `__secret_number2` doesn't exist.

Need to call the function before try to access them, or init them with **init** method.

Comment: Yeah bro.. Tried it. Thanks a lot.